# How to call function inside child (tab) screen from parent screen in react native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So i have a function inside a tab navigator screen, and I want to call from the parent of the tabs.the structure will be like this

[image]

And I need to call a function inside `Tab 2` from `Tabber Screen`, how can I achieve this ?
All that I got from any example is accesing parent prop from child using `screenProps`. nothing is like how I need.

And for information, the parent screen using `StackNavigator` and the tabs using `TabNavigator`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: add some code so that we can understand

Comment: I think it's clear enough to understand, I've mention that if it on the child view we can use screenProps to pass the function from the parent, I need something like this, but on reversed way.